# Merging list based on values

Tags: list

I have 4 lists of different lengths, simplifying:

```
main_lst1= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] - with all values

lst1 = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
lst2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g"]
lst3 = ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

and I need to combine/ merge that lists to get:

```
lst1 = ["a", 0, "c", "d", "e", "f", 0]
lst2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, "g"]
lst3 = [0, 0, "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

I hope that is enough explanation what I need to get.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `lst1`, `lst2`, and `lst3` are alphabetically sorted and that they would only have the characters from `main_lst1`.

Something like this should work:

```
main_lst1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

lst1 = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
lst2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g"]
lst3 = ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

for cur_lst in (lst1, lst2, lst3):
    cur_i = 0
    while len(cur_lst) != len(main_lst1):
        if cur_lst[cur_i] != main_lst1[cur_i]:
            cur_lst.insert(cur_i, 0)
        cur_i += 1
        if cur_i == len(cur_lst):
            cur_lst.append(0)
            break

    print(cur_lst)
```

Basically, I loop over the list and insert 0 when I find that the character doesn't match that of the main list. Of course, if the assumptions I made earlier aren't correct, then this solution will need more alterations to work.

Edit: Also note that since lists are mutable in python, the above code would alter the original lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in Python3. Hope this helps!

```
main_lst1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
lst1 = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
lst2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g"]
lst3 = ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]


def reformat_list(source, target):
    tmp = source
    source = []
    for letter in target:
        if letter in tmp:
            source += [letter]
        else:
            source += ['0']
    return source


lst1 = reformat_list(lst1, main_lst1)
lst2 = reformat_list(lst2, main_lst1)
lst3 = reformat_list(lst3, main_lst1)
print(lst1)
print(lst2)
print(lst3)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).